# Azure SQL - GEO-REPLICATION : Data loss?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, geo-replication

I have an Azure SQL in WEST US with GEO-REPLICATION enabled to sync with EAST US.

and I want to know

1. How often Geo-Recovery sync gets executed to keep the EAST US up to date?
2. In case of WEST US regional failure and happen to failover to EAST US, would there be any data loss?

Comment: Hi @Karthikeyan Vijayakumar , Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

1. Automated backups, according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database#backup-frequency): Both SQL Database and SQL Managed Instance use SQL Server technology to create full backups every week, differential backups every 12-24 hours, and transaction log backups every 5 to 10 minutes. The frequency of transaction log backups is based on the compute size and the amount of database activity.
2. According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-overview?tabs=azure-powershell#preparing-for-data-loss), if an outage is detected, Azure waits for the period you specified by `GracePeriodWithDataLossHours`. The default value is 1 hour. If you cannot afford data loss, make sure to set `GracePeriodWithDataLossHours` to a sufficiently large number, such as 24 hours. Use manual group failover to fail back from the secondary to the primary.
3. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56613545/13979487), Grace period means to allow time for the database to failover within the primary region.

[image]

Comment: What does the Grace period mean? How it will minimize the data loss? Why the number should be large?

Comment: Hi @Karthikeyan Vijayakumar, I've updated my answer.